# getComputedstyle - IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make this code to work in IE8 (and below if possible)?

```
   return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(indicator).getPropertyValue('z-index'), 10);
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: What's the problem with the code in IE8?

Comment: `$(indicator).css('z-index');`?

Comment: 2. getComputedStyle is not supported

Comment: 3. it errors  "Object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> has no method 'css'

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code somewhere:

```
if( !window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(e) {return e.currentStyle};
}
```

Also, you can use `getComputedStyle(indicator).zIndex` to get a property in a cross-browser way.

Comment: When using .currentStyle the z-index return “auto” instead

Comment: I am using this and IE8 throws "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference". What does this mean?